# VS 2012 add-in express plugin

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012, powerpoint, add-in

I'm trying to create a ribbon tab with a new slide button for Powerpoint.
This is the code I used for the button:

```
Dim ppts As PowerPoint.Presentations = PowerPointApp.ActivePresentation
Dim oSlides As PowerPoint.Slides
Dim oSlide As PowerPoint.Slide
Dim oShapes As PowerPoint.Shapes
Dim oShape As PowerPoint.Shape
Dim oTextFrame As PowerPoint.TextFrame
Dim oTextRange As PowerPoint.TextRange
Dim oFont As PowerPoint.Font

oSlides = ppts.Slides
oSlide = oSlides.Add(1, PowerPoint.PpSlideLayout.ppLayoutTitleOnly)
oShapes = oSlide.Shapes
oShape = oShapes.Item(1)
oTextFrame = oShape.TextFrame
oTextRange = oTextFrame.TextRange
oTextRange.Text = "My sample presentation"
oFont = oTextRange.Font
oFont.Name = "Comic Sans MS"
oFont.Size = 48
```

I'm not trying to open a new presentation and add a new slide but add a new slide in the already opened presentation.

I get an error saying:
InvalidCastException was unhandled by user code

Unable to cast COM object of type 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.PresentationClass' to interface type 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.Presentations'. This operation failed because the QueryInterface call on the COM component for the interface with IID '{91493462-5A91-11CF-8700-00AA0060263B}' failed due to the following error: No such interface supported (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80004002 (E_NOINTERFACE)).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Don't you have a syntax error here? (should probably be "Presentation" instead of "PresentationS")
Dim ppts As PowerPoint.Presentations = PowerPointApp.ActivePresentation

Comment: Thanks for replying! but after I changed it had an error: Error while trying to run project uncaught exception thrown by method called through reflection.

Comment: You probably could take a look at the exception message text in debugger, i.e. what does it say (what is the problem), and decide what should be fixed based on that.

Comment: It says: A reference was created to embedded interop assembly 'office' because of an indirect reference to that assembly from assembly 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint'. Consider changing the 'Embed Interop Types' property on either assembly.

Comment: Have you tried to do what the message says- i.e. changing the "Embed Interop Types" of either "Office" or "Powerpoint" assembly?

Comment: How do I do that? I'm not that good at programming sorry.

Comment: In the solution explorer, expand your project node, then expand "References" node, then find the reference to "Office" and "Powerpoint", and in their properties set "Embed interop types" to the same value. May be helpful: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee317478.aspx

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't solve it but I found a solution in the internet where I enable the native code debugging in the Properties>Debug>Enable Debuggers. It shows a message box that says: Debugging information for 'POWERPNT.EXE' cannot be found or does not match. Cannot find or open the PDB file. Do you want to continue debugging? when I click Yes it works but I'm worried it will affect the program I'm working on.